# select rows whose value matches with either of the two columns in the second table:

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, left-join

I have a table that looks like this.

```
id        name
1         firstName
2         secondName
3         thirdName
4         fourthName
```

I want to keep all rows where the name is present in either the "testName" or "prodName" columns from the second table that looks like this:

```
testName        prodName            coordinates
firstName       EN                  124
random          secondName          1244
thirdName       DE                  689
FifthName       DE                  457
```

I want a resulting table that looks like this:

```
id        name                coordinates
1         firstName           124
2         secondName          1244
3         thirdName           689
```

Something like this worked if i was comparing with only one other column from table2:

```
(select * 
  from `table1`
  where exists 
    (select 1
      from `table2` where testName = `table1`.name ));
```

but this would throw an error:

```
(select * 
  from `table1`
  where exists 
    (select 1
      from `table2` where testName = `table1`.name OR prodName = `table1`.name ));
```

```
LEFT SEMI JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join.
```

Comment: Mysql and Google bigquery are two different products. Which one do you use?

Comment: `select *, ifnull(A.coordinates,B.coordinates)  from table1 left join table2 A on table1.name=testName  left join table2 B on table1.name=prodName` the command `ifnull` does not exist in all SQL environments, but with `if` and `case` it is also possible.

Comment: doing a left join adds a lot of extra rows from the second table too @Samuel I have 1000 rows in table1 and 70k in the result

Comment: Can you confirm whether any of the provided answers resolved your issue or not?

Comment: no they didnt actually @kiranmathew

Comment: If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 4):

Please try this:

```
SELECT 
A.id
,A.name
,B.coordinates

FROM table1 A
INNER JOIN table2 B
ON A.name=B.testName OR A.name=B.prodName
```

Comment: No, this gives me 26k rows while the original A table only had 1k. The resulting dataset should be shorter @H

Comment: ah is there any way we can stop checking after one match has been found? For example, if the country_name_en matches, no need to check and match with the next? Maybe there are multiple matches in the B table

Comment: @x89 Please edit the question to show data *actually* representative of the scenario you are dealing with ***and*** the new expected results to demonstrate how you want to handle the multiple matches; if the query legitimately finds multiple matching rows, each with different coordinates, ***you*** need to demonstrate which ***one*** coordinate should be returned.  *(Don't provide additional details that materially change the question as comments, **edit** the question.  At present this answer correctly gives the results you wanted from the example data you proivided.)*

Answer (score 1):

You told that you need the field `coordinate` as well and that is not unique in table2. Here an example for obtaining the maximum of `coordinate`. There is no such thing as first entry in a database, only the value with the first date in another column etc. You did not specify that!

```sql
With table1 as 
(Select row_number() over() as id, * from unnest(["firstName","secondName","thirdName","fourthName"]) name
),table2 as 
(select * from
(select "firstName" as testname, "NB" as prodName
union all select "BG","secondName") ,
unnest(generate_array(1,1)) as coordinates
)
SELECT 
A.id
,A.name
,max(B.coordinates),
max(C.coordinates) as C_coordinates,
avg(ifnull(B.coordinates,C.coordinates)) as coordinate_new,

FROM table1 A
left JOIN table2 B
ON A.name=B.testName 
left JOIN table2 C
ON A.name=C.prodName
group by 1,2
having coordinate_new is not null
```

Here is the example with the `Where` filter:

```sql
With table1 as 
(Select row_number() over() as id, * from unnest(["firstName","secondName","thirdName","fourthName"]) name
),table2 as 
(select "firstName" as testname, "NB" as prodName
union all select "BG","secondName") 

select * 
  from `table1`
  where exists 
    (select 1 from `table2` where testName = `table1`.name
    union all Select 1 from table2 where prodName = `table1`.name )
```

Comment: I cant unset like this because there might be many unique values

Comment: This query is only filtering the table1. If there are duplicate values in table1, there is the need to eleminate or summarize them. Please give a better example as dataset.

Comment: No, I do not need to delete duplicates. Just filter them and add the coordinates column

Answer (score 0):

```
create temp table t1 as(
 select "firstName" as  testName ,"EN" as prodName , 124 as coordinates union all
 select "random","secondName",1244 union all
 select "thirdName","DE",689 union all
 select "FifthName","DE",457
);
 
create temp table t2 as(
select 1 as id,"firstName" as name,124 as coordinates union all
select 2,"secondName",1244 union all
select 3,"thirdName",689
);
 
 
create temp table t3 as(
select a.id as id,a.name as name from  t2 as a where a.id<=0 or exists (select coordinates from t1 as b1 where a.name = b1.testName or a.name=b1.prodName)
);
 
select t3.id,t3.name,t2.coordinates from t3 inner join t2 on t3.name=t2.name;
```

The query is based on whatever data you have provided in the question.
If this does not satisfy your requirement  then please edit the question and add some more details with sample input , output data of your requirement.