# include additional columns while using WHERE IN

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, left-join, where-in

I have a table that looks like this.

```
id        name
1         firstName
2         secondName
3         thirdName
4         fourthName
```

I want to keep all rows where the name is present in either the "Country_name_EN" or "Country_Code" columns from the second table that looks like this:

```
Country_name_EN  Country_Code        coordinates
firstName       EN                  124
random          secondName          1244
thirdName       DE                  689
FifthName       DE                  457
```

I want a resulting table that looks like this. I also want to include the coordinates for all rows where the name is found in table2:

```
id        name                coordinates
1         firstName           124
2         secondName          1244
3         thirdName           689
```

This code works for the joins but not sure how to include the coordinates into it

```
select * 
  from `t1` as test
  where test.name in 
  (select test.name
      from `t2` as geonames 
      where geonames.Country_name_EN = test.name or geonames.Country_Code = test.name)
```

Comment: You posted the same question [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73753208/select-rows-whose-value-matches-with-either-of-the-two-columns-in-the-second-tab)  and got the same answer: You need to do a left join to obtain also the coordinates column. You need to aggregate your results. You do not show that in your sample data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [select rows whose value matches with either of the two columns in the second table:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73753208/select-rows-whose-value-matches-with-either-of-the-two-columns-in-the-second-tab)

Answer (score 1):

A WHERE IN clause can always be rewritten as join, which is usually fatser that IN in big databases, only with a JOIN you can access columns from both tables

So you do

```
SELECT `t1`.id, `t1`.name,`t2`.coordinates
from `t1` JOIN `t2` ON `t1`.name = `t2.Country_name_EN OR  geonames.Country_Code = `t1`.name
```

Comment: But this gives me 26k rows while the original t1 table only had 1k. The resulting dataset should be shorter @H

Comment: then you have in the t2 table multiple names that corresponds to t1, try it in a fiddle the code works with every database and see. Joining is the only way to get the additional column

Comment: ah is there any way we can stop checking after one match has been found? For example, if the country_name_en matches, no need to check and match with the next? @

Comment: You can add a ROW_NUMBER OVER PARTITION BY name) and use an outer sql to limit the number of rows, but as always with limiting the number you need an ORDER BY

Comment: @nbk your answer ist good, but see same discussion as here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73753208/select-rows-whose-value-matches-with-either-of-the-two-columns-in-the-second-tab